# How to grab variable from database and write an if statement

Tags: php, database, variables, conditional-statements, opencart

So, I'm using OpenCart 1.4.9.

What I want to do is grab a variable made by a custom shipping product.

The table in which it's coming from is `product` and the column is `shipping_by_product`:

[image]

I want to add a little picture when browsing through the categories so they can see it's free shipping.

Now, I was able to add this in the product detail (`product.tpl` template):
[image]

Using this code:

```php
<?php if($product_info['shipping_by_product'] == '0.0000'){ ?> 
<img src="LINK HERE" alt="Recommended by MADNESS">
<br />
<?php
} 
?>
```

But that code doesn't work in `category.tpl` (The category template)

I get an undefined index error for `$product_info` and for `shipping_by_product`.

So I was thinking of just running a query to grab the information from the database and then add the conditional, or what other way can I do it?

Comment: Do you have free shipping for entire categories? Or do you need to check all the products in that category first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Added: 'shipping_by_product' => $result['shipping_by_product'], to category.php

As I learned $result is pretty much the same as $product_info in this file.

Then I used this for my code:

```
<?php if($products[$j]['shipping_by_product'] == '0.0000'){ ?> <img style="position: absolute;margin-left: -100px;" src="IMAGE " alt="Free Continental US shipping!"> <br /> <?php } ?>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Data is passed to the template by the controller, which gets it from the model (data layer). You might have to customize the controller and model to get that data if it isn't already passed. You can use the [vqmod](http://ocextensions.ritey.com/how-to-install-vqmod) extension to add your own code in without changing the core code. Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/) for info on the extension.

Comment: No, its by product, each product has a different shipping price, which is in the database under product - shipping_by_product @Revent

Comment: Figured it out.

Added:


    'shipping_by_product'   => $result['shipping_by_product'],

to category.tpl

As I learned $result is pretty much the same as $product_info in this file.

Then I used this for my code:

    <?php if($products[$j]['shipping_by_product'] == '0.0000'){ ?> 
    <img style="position: absolute;margin-left: -100px;" src="IMAGE " alt="Free Continental US shipping!">
    <br />
    <?php
    }
    ?>

:)

Comment: @user2041167 Instead of comment, post Your own solution as Your answer to Your own question and accept it - this way it would be obvious that the question has a solution finally.

Comment: @shadyyx I tried, but it said I couldn't answer it before X hours.